# Cant retrieve second value from same branch in XML file with LINQ

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm triying to get value from  element, from all elemnts under 
but I only   can   get the firs one.
This is the code I used.

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = root 'XDocument.Load("..\..\..\CountryState.xml") '
Dim Header As List(Of Bill) = ( _
From Head In (xdoc.Elements("FILE").Elements("BILL")) _
  Select New Bill With { _
  .countryName = Head.Element("CountryName").Value,
  .Population = Head.Element("Population").Value,
  .ASG_INVOICE_NO = (From el In Head...<ASG_INVOICE_NO> Select el).First(),
  .BillDetail = (From Detail In
      (Head.Element("BILL_SUMM").Element("BILL_SUMM_DETAILS").Element("ADDRESS_GROUP").Elements   ("TARIFF")) _
     Select New BillDetail With { _
      .CIRCUIT_ID = (From D In Detail.Elements("UDFS") _
                Where D.Element("UDF").Elements("COLUMN_NAME").Value  = "CIRCUIT_ID" _
                                            Select  D.<UDF>.<UDF_VALUE>.<VALUE>.Value).FirstOrDefault() _
                                  , .CUSTOM_DESC = (From D In Detail.Elements("UDFS") _
                                         Where D.Element("UDF").Elements("COLUMN_NAME").Value    = "CUSTOM_DESC" _
                                        Select D.<UDF>.<UDF_VALUE>.<VALUE>.Value).FirstOrDefault() _
      }).ToList()}).ToList()
```

The result is Header-> `"Panama 200000 100339"`
the detail on second line Detalle-> `"8000307.SV"`

the values that is missing or not able to get it from the XML is  `"10 Mbps Curacao ECP"`
it shuld show on the second line  beside `"8000307.SV"`  like Detalle-> `"8000307.SV" "10 Mbps Curacao ECP"`

```
For Each H In Header
    Console.WriteLine("Header-> " + H.countryName.Trim + "  " + H.Population.Trim + " " + H.ASG_INVOICE_NO.Trim)
      For Each D In co.BillDetail
          Console.WriteLine("Detalle->  " + D.CIRCUIT_ID + " " + D.CUSTOM_DESC)
      Next D
 Next H
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Great. How does the XML look like? It's hard to help without that...

Comment: Yeah, please update your question with a sample from an XML file, include only relevant nodes, but post a valid XML (all start/end tags intact).